# Message read by OnEntryWritten are coming with parameters not set

Tags: c#, windows, event-log

I'm using the OnEntryWritten event in order to get events from the event log when they are fired.

The problem I started to see today is that some messages come with parameters unset.

For example:

The Windows Filtering Platform has permitted a bind to a local port.  Application Information: Process ID:9852 Application Name:\device\harddiskvolume7\program files (x86)\google\chrome\application\chrome.exe  Network Information: Source Address::: Source Port:51714 Protocol:17  Filter Information: Filter Run-Time ID:0 Layer Name:%%14608 Layer Run-Time ID:38

You can see the %%14608 parameter. This comes with a value if I see the same log in the Event Viewer.

I'm running a windows service as LocalSystem, so I don't know if this is a permission issue or this technology is not useful at all.
I have tried the rest offered on C# and they also don't meet my requirements.

**UPDATE:** this is the code I'm using to read the events.

1) First I subscribe to the corresponding Event log:

```
private void Subscribe()
        {
            _eventLog.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            var callbackFunction = new EntryWrittenEventHandler(OnEntryWritten);
            _eventLog.EntryWritten += callbackFunction;

            // Save a reference for callbackFunction
            _eventHandler = callbackFunction;
        }
```

2) Then on the callback method, I read data from the message:

```
public void OnEntryWritten(Object source, EntryWrittenEventArgs entryArgs)
        {
            // When overwrite policy is enabled, this will trigger for all elements when it starts writing new ones
            try
            {
                var entry = entryArgs.Entry;
                var timeWritten = entry.TimeWritten;

                // This comes with %% values depending on the log
                string message = entry.Message;

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ...
            }
        }
```

3) The event log variable is simply initialized as:

```
var eventLog = EventLog.GetEventLogs().FirstOrDefault(el => el.Log.Equals(logName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

I need some help on this, honestly I don't know what else to try.

**UPDATE**
I'm adding some images here so everybody can understand the situation a little bit better. To be honest, it looks like there's no solution but to implement a dictionary and replace manually the required values, which appear to be always constants.

This is what I see on the Event Viewer for a given Event ID:
[image: Data from Event Viewer]

This is what I see on my program when I read that entry:
[image: Entry being read from program 1]

[image: Entry being read from program 2]

You can clearly see that the following values:

- "Machine key." (Key type)
- "Read persisted key from file." (Operation)

Are coming unmapped in the ReplacementStrings and the Message properties as: %%2499 and %%2458

This is the message value I get on the program:
"Key file operation.\r\n\r\nSubject:\r\n\tSecurity ID:\t\tS-1-5-18\r\n\tAccount Name:\t\tMyAccount$\r\n\tAccount Domain:\t\tWORKGROUP\r\n\tLogon ID:\t\t0x3e7\r\n\r\nProcess Information:\r\n\tProcess ID:\t\t6644\r\n\tProcess Creation Time:\t2019-04-03T12:17:24.587994400Z\r\n\r\nCryptographic Parameters:\r\n\tProvider Name:\tMicrosoft Software Key Storage Provider\r\n\tAlgorithm Name:\tUNKNOWN\r\n\tKey Name:\t816339d2-c476-4f1e-bc40-954f0aa0f851\r\n\tKey Type:\t%%2499\r\n\r\nKey File Operation Information:\r\n\tFile Path:\tC:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\Keys\6d55a45fd69327293e9ed3e7930f4565_5663a8bb-2d1d-4c0d-90c1-624beddabe9c\r\n\tOperation:\t%%2458\r\n\tReturn Code:\t0x0"

What can be done here? There also nothing in entry.Data that might help me out to obtain both values.

Comment: Please post your code, how are you reading this value? args.?

Comment: Sure. I have updated the question with the code being used.

Answer (score 0):

No, I believe you're mistaken, sorry that this answer is too late. I found a similar event that was raised by chrome and evaluated if there's anything missed by the event handler. There wasn't anything missed. The message I got in my console output exactly matched what I saw in my Event Viewer.

A better solution would be to

> Use **entry.Data** to get the complete data instead of *entry.Message*

**entry.Data** will return a `byte[]` which you can convert to a string. Here's the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlogentry?view=netframework-4.7.2) to all properties that an entry will have.

Comment: Hello @kowsikbabu, sadly I'm not mistaken, I see the values in the Event Viewer and they don't come in message when I read it.

Comment: I have tried using entry.Data and it comes empty most of the times. The values I tell you that are coming with "%%" format are in the ReplacementStrings of the Entry.

Comment: Can you attach a sample event data from event viewer and data for the event retrieved programmatically?

Comment: I have updated the question @kowsikbabu so it includes images with what I see on the Event Viewer and on my program.